# 2 How to join two entities in my project

Tags: join, doctrine

I have a relation  one-to-many between project and images and many-to-one between project and propriety. I would to select the procts ho have image.cover=1 and propriety.activated=1 but the code always give me all images for projects

```
class ProjectImage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BI\AdminBundle\Entity\Project", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="id_project", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $idProject;



******************
class Project
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BI\AdminBundle\Entity\Promoteur", inversedBy="projects")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="id_promoteur", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $idPromoteur;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BI\AdminBundle\Entity\Governorate")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="id_governorate")
     */
    private $idGovernorate;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BI\AdminBundle\Entity\Delegation")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, name="id_delegation")
     */
    private $idDelegation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BI\AdminBundle\Entity\Locality")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, name="id_locality")
     */
    private $idLocality;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BI\AdminBundle\Entity\ProjectImage", mappedBy="idProject",cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     */
    private $images;
**********************************
class Promoteur
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "BI\AdminBundle\Entity\Project", mappedBy = "idPromoteur")
     */
    private $projects;
```

Answer (score 0):

On your OneToMany associations, you should use an ArrayCollection since you store can several instances of your target entity on this end. You should also import the ArrayCollection class and instanciate this collection in your constructor.

So in your Project class you may want to add something like this:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="BI\AdminBundle\Entity\ProjectImage", 
   mappedBy="idProject",cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
 */
private $images;

public function __construct() {
    $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Then you can generate the getters and setters with `app/console doctrine:generate:entities`. This command will also create two additional methods `addImage` and `removeImage` to manage your collection.

Hope this will helps

Comment: the problem,i cant explore this method removeElement to select the project ho have cover=1